# How to show GWT UI elements dependent on backing state?

Tags: java, gwt

How can I show UI elements in GWT dependent on a state in the backend?

```
class Login {
    boolean isLogin();
}

<g:Hyperlink text="login/logout" />
```

How can I make the text of the hyperlink dependent on the login state? Can I somehow define if-else statements within ui-binder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no if-else statements in UIBinder.
You have to solve this programatically.

In order to avoid boilerplate you could extend the widgets that should support display state and implenent the functionality in the extended classes or you can use a [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).